# F# passing an operator with arguments to a function

Tags: f#, operators, partial-application

Can you pass in an operation like "divide by 2" or "subtract 1" using just a partially applied operator, where "add 1" looks like this:

```
List.map ((+) 1) [1..5];;  //equals [2..6]
// instead of having to write: List.map (fun x-> x+1) [1..5]
```

What's happening is 1 is being applied to (+) as it's first argument, and the list item is being applied as the second argument.  For addition and multiplication, this argument ordering doesn't matter.

Suppose I want to subtract 1 from every element (this will probably be a common beginners mistake):

```
List.map ((-) 1) [1..5];;  //equals [0 .. -4], the opposite of what we wanted
```

1 is applied to the (-) as its first argument, so instead of `(list_item - 1)`, I get `(1 - list_item)`.  I can rewrite it as adding negative one instead of subtracting positive one:

```
List.map ((+) -1) [1..5];;
List.map (fun x -> x-1) [1..5];; // this works too
```

I'm looking for a more expressive way to write it, something like `((-) _ 1)`, where `_` denotes a placeholder, like in the Arc language.  This would cause `1` to be the second argument to `-`, so in List.map, it would evaluate to `list_item - 1`.  So if you wanted to map `divide by 2` to the list, you could write:

```
List.map ((/) _ 2) [2;4;6] //not real syntax, but would equal [1;2;3] 
List.map (fun x -> x/2) [2;4;6] //real syntax equivalent of the above
```

Can this be done or do I have to use `(fun x -> x/2)`?  It seems that the closest we can get to the placeholder syntax is to use a lambda with a named argument.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could write a flip function, something like:

```
let flip f x y = f y x

List.map (flip (-) 1) [2;4;6]
```

I may have the syntax wrong, I'm not terribly fluent in F#.

Comment: Your flip-function can (just as well) be defined as 'let flip f x y = f y x'

Answer (score 10):

There are no 'operation sections' in F#, a la Haskell, nor placeholder arguments (apparently a la Arc).  You can use a 'flip' combinator as suggested in another answer to reverse the order of arguments and then partially apply the first (now second) argument.

But I would just use

```
fun x -> x / 2
```

Unless you're playing code-golf, I don't think trying to shave another few characters off here buys you anything.

Answer (score 10):

The `flip`-solution suggested by [Logan Capaldo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/61289/logan-capaldo) can also be written using a operator (here `>.`):

```
let (>.) x f = (fun y -> f y x)
List.map (1 >. (-)) [2;4;6]
```

Or if you prefer the operands the other way around:

```
let (>.) f x = (fun y -> f y x)
List.map ((-) >. 1) [2;4;6]
```

**Edit:** Using an operator that "looks more like a placeholder" (here `>-<`) gets you very close to your suggested syntax:

```
List.map ((-) >-< 1) [2;4;6]
```

'_' is unfortunatly(?) not [a valid operator symbol in F#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233204(VS.100).aspx).